# How to get field name from value from a class which has multiple same values for the fields

Tags: java

I'm trying to print the name of the field from the value using `Reflection`. However it works when there are no duplicate fields. But in the below case let's say I have fields with duplicate values and I put them in a `HashMap`. In that case I get incorrect field name.

I chose `HashMap` to store the field names but can some one please tell me if there is any other way to achieve what I'm trying to do

```
public class TestBug {

private static String banana = "green";
private static String apple = "red";
private static String blueberry = "blue";
private static String mango = "green";


private Map<String, String> fillFruitMap() {
    Map<String, String> fruitMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String fruitColor = "";
    String fruitName = "";
    Field[] fields = TestBug.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        try{
            fruitColor = fields[i].get(this).toString();    
            fruitName = fields[i].getName();
            fruitMap.put(fruitColor, fruitName);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return fruitMap;
}

private String getFruitNameFromColor(String color) {
    return fillFruitMap().get(color);
}

private void printStatement(String fruit) {
    System.out.println("Green is the color of "+getFruitNameFromColor(fruit));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestBug bug = new TestBug();
    bug.printStatement(banana);
}
```

}

In the above code Since I'm passing `banana` to the `printStatement` method it should also print `banana` back as I'm using `Reflection` and storing the field value and name as `key` and `value` pair in `HashMap`.
But since `HashMap` doesn't allow duplicate `key`, `banana` was overwritten by `mango`. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Is there a way to do using `hashCode()` ?

Comment: Why can't you have fruit name as key

Answer (score 4):

One option is using `Map<String, List<String>>` instead of `Map<String, String>`

```
private Map<String, List<String>> fillFruitMap() {
    Map<String, List<String>> fruitMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    String fruitColor = "";
    String fruitName = "";
    Field[] fields = TestBug.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        try{
            fruitColor = fields[i].get(this).toString();    
            fruitName = fields[i].getName();
            List<String> list = fruitMap.get(fruitColor);
            if(list == null) list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add(fruitName);
            fruitMap.put(fruitColor, list);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return fruitMap;
}
```

Comment: Even if I have a <String, List<String>> how can I get banana if I pass banana method? As I'd be iterating through the List and finally how do I know that I should print banana and not mango?

Comment: That's a question for you to answer. How would you know which fruit you want, since both banana and mango have the same color?

Comment: Since I passed "banana" it should pick "banana" from the `List`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you picked a wrong representation: since value-to-field is not a one-to-one (as you have noticed) but one-to-many, your code should return `Map<String,List<String>>` instead of `Map<String,String>`:

```
private Map<String,List<String>> fillFruitMap() {
    Map<String, String> fruitMap = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
    String fruitColor = "";
    String fruitName = "";
    Field[] fields = TestBug.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        try{
            fruitColor = fields[i].get(this).toString();    
            fruitName = fields[i].getName();
            List<String> list = fruitMap.get(fruitColor);
            if (list == null) {
                list = new ArrayList<String>();
                fruitMap.put(fruitColor, list);
            }
            list.add(fruitName);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return fruitMap;
}
```

This would let you store the names of all fields with the desired value. Of course the code that uses this updated `fillFruitMap` should change as well. Specifically, it needs to be prepared to print lists, not single strings, when iterating the map.

Comment: Even if I have a <String, List<String>> how can I get `banana` if I pass `banana` method? As I'd be iterating through the `List` and finally how do I know that I should print banana and not mango?

Comment: @user1629109 "Since I passed "banana" it should pick "banana"..." No, you didn't pass `"banana"`, you passed the **value** of the variable called `banana`, but the value is `"green"`. Your program has no way to find out the name of the variable that you have passed.

Comment: Yeah. That's the problem I'm facing. Do you know if there is a way to store the `hashCode` and compare the hashCode and get what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @user1629109 Hash code does not play into it at all. Disambiguating a field by a value alone is not possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.